# How to read Github projects?

Tags: github, mono, open-source

Blunder software engineer is here, please don't go brutal.:)

Recently I have downloaded the the [Mono](https://github.com/mono/mono) 
project to my PC, there are tons of code inside of it. So my question is, how do you read and understand such big project. I know the documentations are exist for it, but do you really understand something when you deep into the codes? Is it the way the figuring out structure of the software? If not, what is it?

And I can't reasoning open sourcing a project, most of those don't even understand and take a look of it. What is  the exact reason of opensourcing?

Answer (score 0):

This is all you need to know about open source

https://opensource.org/osd-annotated

https://opensource.com/resources/what-open-source